# Display File upload dialog box onclick Mask images

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two types of images in our json files....

1.**Mask** images

- Which have Transparent background as below :

[image]

2.**Background** images :

- Any normal images

Sample Json for **Mask** image :

In JSON , mask images names will start with "**mask_**"

```
            {             
              "src" : "image1.png",              
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
```

Sample Json for **Background** images :

```
            {             
              "src" : "image2.png",              
              "name" : "bg_image"
            },
```

Right now , **both** the images are **clickable** , means once we click on Images, we are displaying **File upload Dialog Box**....

**Requirement** :

Only Mask images should be clickable & not Background images....

So i added this condition for container , but after that, both images become unclickable....

```
if (name.indexOf('mask_')! == -1) 
  {
    $('.container').click(function(e) 
     {
        // container code here
     });
  }
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/GeVbea

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/kidsdial1/s9xfo4zj/7/

Below is Code snippet :

```js
var target;
var imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {  
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 1012,   
      "layers" : [        
        {
          "x" : 365,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,            
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,              
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            }            
          ],
          "y" : 21,         
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,         
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,             
              "src" : "iEA642D.jpg",
              "y" : 0,             
              "name" : "bg_image"
            }            
          ],
          "y" :22,         
          "name" : "L2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0, 
      "width" : 1012,   
      "name" : "L1"
    }
  ]
};


$(document).ready(function() {

    // below code will upload image onclick mask image

   $('.container').click(function(e) {

        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        console.log(target);
        if (e.target.getContext) 
  {            
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);           
        }
    });
 
 
 // Below code will fetch mask images from json file
 
    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
     name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
      name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
       name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

     function json(data)
        {           
            let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
            let layer1 = data.layers;            
            let counter = 0;
            let table = [];

            for (let {
                    src,
                    x,
                    y,
     name
                } of arr) {
                
                   
                var mask = $(".container").mask({                
        imageUrl: imageUrl,     
                    maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                        img.css({
                            "position": "absolute",
                            "left": x + "px",
                            "top": y + "px"
                        });

                    },
                    id: counter
                });
                table.push(mask);
                fileup.onchange = function() {

                    let mask2 = table[target];
                    mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                    document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";                        
                };
                counter++;      
            }
        }

json(jsonData);
}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;
        
        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function()
                {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };

        function renderInnerImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
            img.src = settings.imageUrl;
            img.onload = function() {
                settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                initImage = false;
            };
        }

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
             console.log("load");
            //if (img)
               // img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle().then(renderInnerImage);
        };

        // change the masked Image
         container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {}

.container {
 background: gold;
  position: relative;
 width:812px;
 height:812px;
}

.container img {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:250px;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   margin:auto;
   z-index:999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden; 
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer{ position:absolute;  text-align:center; color:#FFF}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `pointer-events: none` using JS so that is not clickable

```
if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) {
    var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
} else {
    var imageUrl1 = '';
    $('.masked-img').css('pointer-events', 'none');
}
```