# Fetch two images from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are fetching 2 images using JSON - Mask image & Car

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/x80rcwzj/1/

Due to some reasons, i changed some code in below functions in above fiddle:

```
container.scaleMask [ container.drawMask ]
function renderInnerImage [ container.drawImage ]
container.loadImage
container.loadMaskImage
```

**Issue** :

Now Car image is not displaying : 
https://jsfiddle.net/m0pfoa5L/1/

Here is CodePen: https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/RmBxZz

Below is Code Snippet :

```js
var target;
        const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

        let jsonData = {
            "layers": [{
                "x": 0,
                "height": 612,
                "layers": [{
                    "x": 160,
                    "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
                    "y": 91,
                    "height": 296,
                    "width": 429,
                    "name": "mask_1"
                }, {
                    "x": 25,
                    "src": "iEA642D.jpg",
                    "height": 324,
                    "width": 471,
                    "y": 22,
                    "name": "car"
                }],
                "y": 0,
                "width": 612
            }]
        };

        const containerElement = $('#container');
        const fileUp = $('#fileup');
        let mask;

        $(function() {

            // Upload image onclick mask image 

            containerElement.click(function(e) {
                var res = e.target;
                target = res.id;
                if (e.target.getContext) {
                    // click only inside Non Transparent part 
                    var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
                    if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            $('#fileup').click();
                        }, 20);
                    }
                }
            });

            // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code 

            function getAllSrc(layers) {
                let arr = [];
                layers.forEach(layer => {
                    if (layer.src) {
                        arr.push({
                            src: layer.src,
                            x: layer.x,
                            y: layer.y,
                            height: layer.height,
                            width: layer.width,
                            name: layer.name
                        });
                    } else if (layer.layers) {
                        let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                        if (newArr.length > 0) {
                            newArr.forEach(({
                                src,
                                x,
                                y,
                                height,
                                width,
                                name
                            }) => {
                                arr.push({
                                    src,
                                    x: (layer.x + x),
                                        y: (layer.y + y),
                                        height,
                                        width,
                                        name: (name)
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                return arr;
            }

            function json(data) {
                var width = 0;
                var height = 0;

                let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
                let layer1 = data.layers;
                width = layer1[0].width;
                height = layer1[0].height;
                let counter = 0;
                let table = [];

                // container dimensions 
                containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
                //end 

                for (let {
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        name
                    }
                    of arr) {

                    //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ] 
                    var ImagePosition = arr;
                    //code end 

                    if(name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1){
                    var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;
                }else{
                    var imageUrl1 = '';
                }

                    var mask = $(".container").mask({
                        imageUrl: imageUrl1,

                        // Fetch Mask images 
                        maskImageUrl: 'http://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                        // end 

                        onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                            // Mask image positions 
                            img.css({
                                "position": "absolute",
                                "left": x + "px",
                                "top": y + "px"
                            });
                            // end 

                        },
                        id: counter
                    });
                    // here 
                    table.push(mask);
                    fileup.onchange = function() {

                        let mask2 = table[target];
                        const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                        document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";
                        
                    };
                    counter++;
                }
                return mask;
            }
            mask = json(jsonData);
        }); // end of function 

        // Image code 

        (function($) {
            window.JQmasks = [];
            $.fn.mask = function(options) {
                // This is the easiest way to have default options. 
                var settings = $.extend({
                    // These are the defaults. 
                    maskImageUrl: undefined,
                    imageUrl: undefined,
                    scale: 1,
                    id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
                    x: 0, // image start position 
                    y: 0, // image start position 
                    onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
                }, options);

                // Create the image properties
                settings.maskImage = new Image
                settings.image  = new Image

                // set the cross-origin attributes
                settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

                settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
                    // once the mask is loaded, load the image
                    container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl)
                }

                settings.image.onload = function() {
                    // once the image is loaded, render to canvas
                    container.drawMask()
                    container.drawImage()
                }

                var container = $(this);

                let prevX = 0,
                    prevY = 0,
                    draggable = false,
                    img,
                    canvas,
                    context,
                    image,
                    timeout,
                    initImage = false,
                    startX = settings.x,
                    startY = settings.y,
                    div;               

                container.drawMask = function() {
                    canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
                    canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
                    context.save();
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                    // draw the masked image after scaling 
                    context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage.height);
                    context.restore()
                };

                container.drawImage = function() {
       
                    const img = settings.image     

                    settings.x = (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2
                    settings.y = (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2

                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                }

                // change the draggable image 

                container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
                    
                    settings.y = startY;
                    settings.x = startX;
                    prevX = prevY = 0;

                    initImage = true;

                    settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED

                    // sirpepole Add this 
                    return settings.id;
                };

                container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
                    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
                    canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
                    // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
                    settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

                    div = $("<div/>", {
                        "class": "masked-img"
                    }).append(canvas);

                    // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) 
                    div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                        if (event.handled === false) return;
                        event.handled = true;
                        container.onDragStart(event);
                    });

                    div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                        if (event.handled === false) return;
                        event.handled = true;
                        container.selected(event);
                    });

                    div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);

                    container.append(div);
                    if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                        settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);

                    // container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
                    // Moved this to the settings.maskImage.onload
                };
                container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
                JQmasks.push({
                        item: container,
                        id: settings.id
                    })
                    // Edit image 
                div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
                div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
                // ends 
                return container;
            };
        }(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
        background: silver;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .container img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 250px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        z-index: 999;
    }
    
    .masked-img {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none">

    <div id="container" class="container">
    </div>
```

**Hint** :

if I replace `"name": "car"` by `"name": "mask_something"`, then car image will display, but in that case, a small icon will display on the car, but I don't want that...

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what is the goal here. I have a feeling the it way overwhelm. Can you describe with simple words what is the product / feature here? What it's meant to do?

Comment: @MoshFeu once we click on `mask image` user can upload his own image..... so that user can upload their own image and click on save, then we will print that product and send to them : `invitation card, t-shirt`.....

Comment: @MoshFeu can you please compare [old code](https://jsfiddle.net/x80rcwzj/1/) and [new code](https://jsfiddle.net/m0pfoa5L/1/) & tell me what is the reason that car is not displaying....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trie to mask an image, but you are not loading the image because of your `name.indexOf('mask_')` if condition.

Therefore the car is not shown, because its name is `masknot_`. Because the image has no url nothing is shown. If you remove that if condition both images (car and icon) are shown, because your code says mask image with image2. But that is exactly what the `mask` function is for. To mask an image with another image.

So you could apply the if condition to the image that will be shown above the car to not show it if `masknot_` is in the name. That is an option, but it is not recommended because a masking function should mask something.

Write a new function to display an image without applying a mask would be the best option.

Below is a working example of your code.

```
var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 612,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 160,
            "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
            "y": 91,
            "height": 296,
            "width": 429,
            "name": "mask_1"
        }, {
            "x": 25,
            "src": "iEA642D.jpg",
            "height": 324,
            "width": 471,
            "y": 22,
            "name": "car"
        }],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {

    // Upload image onclick mask image 

    containerElement.click(function(e) {
        var res = e.target;
        target = res.id;
        if (e.target.getContext) {
            // click only inside Non Transparent part 
            var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
            if (pixel[3] === 255) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $('#fileup').click();
                }, 20);
            }
        }
    });

    // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code 

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                                y: (layer.y + y),
                                height,
                                width,
                                name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data) {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions 
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end 

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            }
            of arr) {

            //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ] 
            var ImagePosition = arr;
            //code end 


            var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;


            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 ? imageUrl1 : undefined,

                // Fetch Mask images 
                maskImageUrl: 'http://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                // end 

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions 
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end 

                },
                id: counter
            });
            // here 
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

            };
            counter++;
        }
        return mask;
    }
    mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function 

// Image code 

(function($) {
    window.JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options. 
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults. 
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position 
            y: 0, // image start position 
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);

        // Create the image properties
        settings.maskImage = new Image
        settings.image  = new Image

        // set the cross-origin attributes
        settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
        settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

        settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
            // once the mask is loaded, load the image
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl)
          container.drawMask()
        }

        settings.image.onload = function() {
            // once the image is loaded, render to canvas

            container.drawImage()
        }

        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;               

        container.drawMask = function() {
            if (!settings.maskImage) return true;
            canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
            canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
            // draw the masked image after scaling 
            if (settings.maskImage) context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage.height);
            context.restore()
        };

        container.drawImage = function() {

            const img = settings.image                  

            settings.x = (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2
            settings.y = (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
            if (img) context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
          context.restore()
            initImage = false;
        }

        // change the draggable image 

        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (!imageUrl) return true;
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;

            initImage = true;

            settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED

            // sirpepole Add this 
            return settings.id;
        };

        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {

            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) 
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);

            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);

            // container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
            // Moved this to the settings.maskImage.onload
        };
        if (settings.maskImageUrl) {
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        }
        JQmasks.push({
                item: container,
                id: settings.id
            })
            // Edit image 
        div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
        div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
        // ends 
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code working fine here : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/OYwZEM , please tell what code changes you have done.....

Comment: Created a [Gist Diff](https://gist.github.com/dominicrico/abfc3f295daf1ea2e6e6cd83c7905a81/revisions) for you

Comment: Thanks for that, i need one more help from you, only mask images [ plus icon ] should be clickable, in codepen : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/OYwZEM , onclick `car` , its displaying `file upload dialog box`, but that should be not clickable.... previously i used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492207/display-file-upload-dialog-box-onclick-mask-images) , but now i have different code....

Comment: Your click function right now only checks if the pixel you are clicking is not transparent. You should also check if the clicked pixel is inside the x and y coordinates of the icon.