# Add IF condition to clickable images to ascertain a pixel value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

We have 2 images that we fetched from JSON:

1.Mask image [  name starts with **mask_** ]

2.Car image [ name starts with other than **mask_** ]

[image]

**Requirement** :

`onclick` Mask image , i want to display file upload dialog box. it's working fine. but `onclick` car image, i don't want to display file upload dialog box.

**Issue** :

`onclick` car image,  file upload dialog box is displaying. but Car image should't be clickable because it's name started with "other than `mask_`"

I tried `$('.masked-img').css('pointer-events', 'none');` but it did't helped me.

Below is Snippet :

```js
var target;
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/RzEm1WK.png";

let jsonData = {
  "layers": [{
    "x": 0,
    "height": 612,
    "layers": [{
        "x": 70,
        "src": "ax0HVTs.png",
        "y": 199,
        "height": 296,
        "width": 429,
        "name": "mask_1"
      },
      {
        "name": "car",
        "x": 25,
        "src": "iEA642D.jpg",
        "height": 324,
        "width": 471,
        "y": 22

      }
    ],
    "y": 0,
    "width": 612
  }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');
let mask;

$(function() {
  // Upload image onclick mask image 
  containerElement.click(function(e) {
    var res = e.target;
    target = res.id;
    if (e.target.getContext) {
      // click only inside Non Transparent part 
      var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
      if (pixel[3] === 255) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          $('#fileup').click();
        }, 20);
      }
    }
  });

  // Fetch mask images from json file - IGNORE this code 

  function getAllSrc(layers) {
    let arr = [];
    layers.forEach(layer => {
      if (layer.src) {
        arr.push({
          src: layer.src,
          x: layer.x,
          y: layer.y,
          height: layer.height,
          width: layer.width,
          name: layer.name
        });
      } else if (layer.layers) {
        let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
        if (newArr.length > 0) {
          newArr.forEach(({
            src,
            x,
            y,
            height,
            width,
            name
          }) => {
            arr.push({
              src,
              x: (layer.x + x),
              y: (layer.y + y),
              height,
              width,
              name: (name)
            });
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return arr;
  }

  function json(data) {
    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;

    let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);
    let layer1 = data.layers;
    width = layer1[0].width;
    height = layer1[0].height;
    let counter = 0;
    let table = [];

    // container dimensions 
    containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
    //end 

    for (let {
        src,
        x,
        y,
        name
      } of arr) {

      //Get Height and width of mask image [ edit button ] 
      var ImagePosition = arr;
      //code end 


      var imageUrl1 = imageUrl;


      var mask = $(".container").mask({
        imageUrl: name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1 ? imageUrl1 : undefined,

        // Fetch Mask images 
        maskImageUrl: 'http://i.imgur.com/' + src,
        // end 

        onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
          // Mask image positions 
          img.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "left": x + "px",
            "top": y + "px"
          });
          // end 

        },
        id: counter
      });
      // here 
      table.push(mask);
      fileup.onchange = function() {

        let mask2 = table[target];
        const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
        document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";

      };
      counter++;
    }
    return mask;
  }
  mask = json(jsonData);
}); // end of function 

// Image code 

(function($) {
  window.JQmasks = [];
  $.fn.mask = function(options) {
    // This is the easiest way to have default options. 
    var settings = $.extend({
      // These are the defaults. 
      maskImageUrl: undefined,
      imageUrl: undefined,
      scale: 1,
      id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
      x: 0, // image start position 
      y: 0, // image start position 
      onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
    }, options);

    // Create the image properties
    settings.maskImage = new Image
    settings.image = new Image

    // set the cross-origin attributes
    settings.maskImage.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    settings.image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

    settings.maskImage.onload = function() {
      // once the mask is loaded, load the image
      container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl)
      container.drawMask()
    }

    settings.image.onload = function() {
      // once the image is loaded, render to canvas

      container.drawImage()
    }

    var container = $(this);

    let prevX = 0,
      prevY = 0,
      draggable = false,
      img,
      canvas,
      context,
      image,
      timeout,
      initImage = false,
      startX = settings.x,
      startY = settings.y,
      div;

    container.drawMask = function() {
      if (!settings.maskImage) return true;
      canvas.width = settings.maskImage.width;
      canvas.height = settings.maskImage.height;
      context.save();
      context.beginPath();
      context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
      // draw the masked image after scaling 
      if (settings.maskImage) context.drawImage(settings.maskImage, 0, 0, settings.maskImage.width, settings.maskImage.height);
      context.restore()
    };

    container.drawImage = function() {

      const img = settings.image

      settings.x = (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2
      settings.y = (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2

      context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
      if (img) context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
      context.restore()
      initImage = false;
    }

    // change the draggable image 

    container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
      if (!imageUrl) return true;
      settings.y = startY;
      settings.x = startX;
      prevX = prevY = 0;

      initImage = true;

      settings.image.src = imageUrl; // CHANGED

      // sirpepole Add this 
      return settings.id;
    };

    container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {

      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
      canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
      // settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
      settings.maskImage.src = imageUrl // CHANGED

      div = $("<div/>", {
        "class": "masked-img"
      }).append(canvas);

      // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) 
      div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {
        if (event.handled === false) return;
        event.handled = true;
        container.onDragStart(event);
      });

      div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
        if (event.handled === false) return;
        event.handled = true;
        container.selected(event);
      });

      div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);

      container.append(div);
      if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
        settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);

      // container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
      // Moved this to the settings.maskImage.onload
    };
    if (settings.maskImageUrl) {
      container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
    }
    JQmasks.push({
      item: container,
      id: settings.id
    })
    // Edit image 
    div.addClass('masked-img' + settings.id);
    div.attr('data-id', settings.id);
    // ends 
    return container;
  };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
  background: silver;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 250px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" />
<div id="container" class="container"></div>
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/VOVyoG), [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7g1fd32/) & [Full code in pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hCFRNSAY)

We implemented similar feature that displaying "+" icon only on mask images....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for...Of` loops are helped in this question, by mapping you are fetch `mask` images
and using help of `includes` function you can search it and after you can add `pointer-events` CSS property.

```js
ImagePosition.map(function (cur, index) {
    var available = cur.name.includes('mask_');

    if (!available) {
        $('.masked-img' + index).css('pointer-events', 'none');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the data of one pixel and it returns a Uint8ClampedArray which is 4 bytes long.

```
var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
```

Now these 4 bytes represent the R, G, B and A value of the pixel. The `pixels[3]` represents the Alpha value which can be 255 easily for most of the images.

If you want to make sure that only the White pixels should trigger the action, you should check for R, G and B for 255.

```
if (pixel[0] === 255 && pixel[1] === 255 && pixel[2] === 255) {
     setTimeout(() => {
         $('#fileup').click();
     }, 20);
}
```

**Hint:**

There is a design flaw in your program. That is, if your image (the car or anything) has White pixels and the user clicks on one of them, the action would be taken. You should check for a clicks on the mask region and then look for White pixels.

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine....but is it possible to restrict based on `if image_name don't start with mask_` as [in this link's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492207/display-file-upload-dialog-box-onclick-mask-images)

Comment: Since you are drawing it on the same canvas, the data is already mixed and there is no way you can find which file the data came from. Concentrate on the region you draw the mask in.

Comment: instead of if condition, i think what you gave is more better solution ;)

Comment: You still need the IF condition - but to check the clicked spot is in a certain bound box - not to check the color of the clicked spot.

Comment: yes, you are right, but i said : i dont need if condition for restricting based on image_name , like this : `if (name.indexOf('mask_') !== -1) ` , what you gave is more generic solution.....

Comment: omg, i can't able to upload when i click on plus icon as here :

Comment: That is because the pixels are not white there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194232/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-charlie-h).